# How to select two links at once? (i.e. Title & Image)

Tags: javascript, css, hyperlink

i'm wondering how to achieve this kind of thumbnail gallery...

http://cargocollective.com/saintea

like when you roll over the thumbnail,

it gives an highlight effect to the title at the same time even though they are two separate elements.

I could make them as one file, but the reason why I want to have them separate is to assign

different effects :) !

can someone please lend me a hand?

thank you so much for reading this post !!!

have a great day !

Answer (score 2):

It's just two `<div>`s in a link tag. But block elements in inline elements aren't valid, so you could better use `<span>` elements in a link tag like this:

HTML:

```
<a href="#">
  <span class="one">text</span>
  <span class="two">something else</span>
</a>

a:link span, a:visited span {
  display: block; /* <-- for example */
  color: blue;
}
```

CSS:

```
a:hover span.one {
  color: yellow;
}

a:hover span.two {
  color: orange;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers indicate, you could do it with both javascript and CSS. The page uses javascript and the framework [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) to do it.

I made a demo of how it can be done both ways: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/n25Vu/).

Given the following HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="theLink">
    <img id="theImage" src="http://dummyimage.com/100x50/000/fff&text=Some+image" />
    <span id="theText">Some text</span>
</a>
```

You can either do it with jQuery (this is roughly how that page does it):

```
$("#theImage").hover(
    function() {
        $(this).fadeTo("fast", 0.7);
        $("#theText").addClass("hover");
    },
    function() {
        $(this).fadeTo("fast", 1);
        $("#theText").removeClass("hover");
    }
);
```

where the class `hover` styles the text.

Here, you are telling jQuery to fire one function when you hover *over* the image, and another function when you hover *out of* the image. `$("this).fadeTo` sets the opacity of the image, while `$("#theText").addClass`.. well, it adds the class to `theText`.

(ofcourse, you don't *need* jQuery to do this, it's just very handy to use such a framework because it abstracts away much of the work)

---

Or with CSS:

```
#imagelink:hover img {
    /* See http://www.quirksmode.org/css/opacity.html for opacity */
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=70)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=70);    
    opacity: 0.7;
}
#imagelink:hover span {
    background-color: #66E8FF;
}
```

Here we're telling the browser that when we hover over the link with the id `imagelink`, the contents inside the link of type `img` should have an opacity of 70%, while elements of the type `span` should have a different background color.

Answer (score 1):

It's perfectly acceptable to wrap just about any elements within a single anchor element. Most browsers already support this, and w/ HTML5 it's actually preferred. So I would just do:

```
<a href="#">
    <img src="image.jpg" width="" height="" alt="" >
    <p>Description of the image</p>
</a>

a:hover img { }
a:hover p { }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it the following way:

```
<img src="image.gif" 
  onmouseover="change image style, then change getElementById('comment') style" 
  onmouseout="change all back"/>
<span id="comment">some text</span>
```